# appWidget not showing in launcher widget list in lollipop devices only

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I have an app for android which I already made an appwidget for it before lollipop , for some reasons the widget doesn't appear in lollipop. However, it is showing up in the pre-lollipop devices.

Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".widgets.NewsWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >>
        <intent-filter >
            <action
                android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/news_info" />
</receiver>
```

news_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_news"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:minWidth="300dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="6000000" >
```

NewsWidgetProvider.java

```
public class NewsWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static final String NEXT_NEWS = "NEXT_NEWS";
private static final String PREVIOUS_NEWS = "PREVIOUS_NEWS";
private static final String GO_TO_NEWS_ACTIVITY = "GO_TO_NEWS_ACTIVITY";
private final String NEWS_LIST_KEY = "newsList";
NewsItem[] news;
int currentNews=0;
Bitmap imageBitmap;
private final String CURRENT_NEWS_KEY = "currentNews";

@Override
public void onUpdate(final Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int[] appWidgetIds) {

    startService(context);

    loadItemFromSharedPreference(context);

    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        setUpView(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds, widgetId);
    }

}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    loadItemFromSharedPreference(context);

    if (news != null) {
        if (GO_TO_NEWS_ACTIVITY.equals(intent.getAction())){
        openNewsActivity(context);
    }

        else if (NEXT_NEWS.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            if (currentNews == news.length - 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "reached last news", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        else if (news.length - 1 > currentNews) {
            currentNews++;
            SharedPreferencesManager.putInteger(context, CURRENT_NEWS_KEY, currentNews);
            loadItemFromSharedPreference(context);
            setTheCurrentView(context);
        }
        }
    else if (PREVIOUS_NEWS.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                if (currentNews == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.last_item), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (currentNews > 0 && news != null) {
                    currentNews--;
                    SharedPreferencesManager.putInteger(context, CURRENT_NEWS_KEY, currentNews);
                    loadItemFromSharedPreference(context);
                    setTheCurrentView(context);
                }
            }

    }
}

private void setUpView(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds, int widgetId) {
    final RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_news);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, news==null?context.getString(R.string.wait_msg):news[currentNews].title);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.brief,news==null?"":news[currentNews].brief);
    setPendingIntents(context, appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    if (news!=null) {
        if (imageBitmap!=null) {
            AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
            remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, aq.getCachedImage(news[currentNews].imageUrl, 100));
        }
        else {
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.image,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    }
    else {
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.image,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
}


private void setTheCurrentView(Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_news);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, news==null?context.getString(R.string.widget_problem_title):news[currentNews].title);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.brief,news==null?context.getString(R.string.widget_problem_breif):news[currentNews].brief);
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, imageBitmap);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName( context, NewsWidgetProvider.class );
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget( thisWidget, remoteViews );
}

private void openNewsActivity(Context context) {
    Intent o=new Intent(context, NewsActivity.class);
    o.putExtra(NewsItem.EXTRA_NEWS_ITEM,news[currentNews]);
    o.putExtra(NewsItem.EXTRA_NEWS_SOURCE_IS_PUSH_OR_WIDGET,true);
    o.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(o);
}

private void setPendingIntents(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next_news, getPendingSelfIntent(context, NEXT_NEWS, appWidgetIds));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.previous_news,getPendingSelfIntent(context,PREVIOUS_NEWS,appWidgetIds));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.title,getPendingSelfIntent(context,GO_TO_NEWS_ACTIVITY,appWidgetIds));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.brief,getPendingSelfIntent(context,GO_TO_NEWS_ACTIVITY,appWidgetIds));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image,getPendingSelfIntent(context,GO_TO_NEWS_ACTIVITY,appWidgetIds));
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action,int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, intent, 0);
    return pendingIntent;
}
private void loadItemFromSharedPreference(Context context) {

    currentNews=SharedPreferencesManager.getInteger(context, CURRENT_NEWS_KEY, 0);
    news=SharedPreferencesManager.getObject(context, NEWS_LIST_KEY,NewsItem[].class);
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
    imageBitmap= news == null ? BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher) : aq.getCachedImage(news[currentNews].imageUrl,200);
}

private void startService(Context context) {
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, NewsWidgetService.class );
    //only start service if news is null
    if (SharedPreferencesManager.getObject(context, NEWS_LIST_KEY, NewsItem[].class)==null)
        context.startService(broadcastIntent);
}
```

}

The code is working in (kitkat,jelly...) but it's not working in lollipop

Am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same bug on Genymotion 4.3 using Google Now Launcher, which is the default launcher in Lollipop, so the problem lies within the launcher and not Lollipop per se

Comment: I see the same problem with Whatsapp and the Facebook app, but strangely enough not with Evernote

Comment: What's the device you are running lollipop and trying to show your widget on?

Comment: i used nexus 5 and Galaxy s5 @Libelle

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. By the way, I noticed that your appwidget-provider tag in news_info.xml doesn't have closing tag. The last line should end with '6000000" />'. (Note the / before closing bracket)

Comment: @Samer Zuhair Hi please post your code to load image from url using auery. I'm in urgent need of this.

Comment: @Sangeetha sorry I no longer have access to that code and have stopped using aquery since that project however, check this link it might help you 

http://androiddhina.blogspot.com/2015/03/androiddownload-image-using-aquery.html

Comment: @Samer Zuhair Okay. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - i fixed it by adding additional parameter **android:widgetCategory="home_screen"** to appwidget-provider:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:configure="com.example.activities.ConfigurationActivity"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
    android:resizeMode="none">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: Did you change anything else? My code looks very similar to yours but I see no App Widget on Lollipop devices.

Comment: still got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on Google Now Launcher. I found that a workaround for this is to add a dummy ContentProvider to your app. You can see how to do that on [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854565/android-appwidget-not-adding-to-homescreen-on-lollipop/29572345#29572345).

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens with me when installing widgets from Play Store and even when I install directly from Android Studio during development.

Solutions worked for me:

- Rebooting the device after initial application/appwidget install worked for me.
- Installing a custom launcher